# object oriented programming inheritance

Tags: php, class, visibility

I have created this parent class

```
class DBMysqli {
    private $mysqli;

    function __construct($Mysqli) {
        $this->mysqli = $Mysqli;
    }

     public function GET($queryArr){

        $query = "SELECT ";

       ...

        $result = $this->mysqli->query($query); //Here I get a run time error!!
        echo $this->mysqli->error;

        return $result;
   }
}
```

and a child class

```
class FolderComment extends DBMysqli{

    protected $data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = DB::Simulator(); //works, initiliaze $mysqli
        $table = array(
            'tables' => 'folder_comments',
            'conditions' => '1'
        );

        $this->data = $this->GET($table);
    }
}
```

I get run time error, stating that the $this->mysqli is null. but I have set it in the child class. I guess this is an OOP understating question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
private $mysqli;
```

To

```
protected $mysqli;
```

In the prent class

Answer (score 1):

I believe that since you have made mysqli a private variable, it is not getting set in the child's constructor as you presume. It should be protected if you want children to be able to access it.

So instead what is happening is that you are creating a new variable in your child class called `mysqli`, since it never inherited the private field from the parent in the first place.

Your other option would be to call the parent's constructor implicitly and send it the `mysqli` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass on mysqli object to your parent class

```
   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(DB::Simulator());
        $table = array(
            'tables' => 'folder_comments',
            'conditions' => '1'
        );

        $this->data = $this->GET($table);
    }
```

Comment: +1  I would go with this solution,  although everyone is correct.  IMO $mysqli is part of the encapsulated implementation of DMmysqli and should be private, I think this was the intention and not the mistake.  Setup of this dependency was provided in the DMmysqli constructor so the existing contract should be obeyed by calling the parent constructor.  In PHP parent constructors are not called implicitly so you must call the parent yourself.

Comment: That's a whole architecture change, while perhaps a valid point (dependency injection is a great thing) it further means he should not be using inheritance at all... instead of `$this->get` it should be `$this->db->get`, and why make the mistake of constructing inside the child class when you could just pass in the connection as with the parent?

Comment: @Rudu I agree in principle, I think I saw some signs of an attempt at encapsulation though, so I saw this solution as the direction devmonster was aiming for. Likely not really wanting to raise the bar to full on DIP, rather just a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In `DBMysqli` you need `$mysqli` to be `protected`, not `private`

```
class DBMysqli {
    protected $mysqli;
    //...
```

**Private** says that any access - either external or inherited is prevented, while **protected** says external access is prevented but inherited objects can access the property.